# DevExpress Report Designer MVC make subreport use main report datasource

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, devexpress, datasource, subreport

I am placing a report designer on my website for users to design reports with.  The user will make a selection from a dropdown and depending on the selection, a DevExpress ReportDesigner loads with the appropriate datasource binded to it.  I have successfully achieved this, however, if the user adds a subreport to the report, the main report datasource is not passed down to the subreport.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Subreport should use its own DataSource.

but you can pass "master" dataousrce on the "[BeforePrint](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_BeforePrinttopic)" event.

how to pass datasource to the subreport: [one](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q369488) and [two](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q569025)